# Need to implement SVN hooks on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am working on SVN on windows and Now I am increasing my knowledge boundaries by exploring SVN in deep. I just came through the hooks which can be helpful to tracking the records. I am working on Windows 7 and VisualSVN. I need to implement post-commit hook to automate the process ina way that if any develpoer commits in any file in Repo, an email will be triggered containing about the file and autor.

Please let know which file I need to modify and how.

Answer (score 1):

Use `VisualSVNServerHooks.exe` built-in hook: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/.

Comment: what should I give the value in this -> --from <from-email> --to <to-email> ^
    --smtp-server <smtp-server>

Comment: @R.Sha the linked page contains an example at the bottom.

Comment: thanks but I need to configure this acorss my organisation, so is there any wau I can configure smtp on windows.

Comment: @R.Sha ask your system administrator whether you have a local SMTP server.

Comment: I got this error while using below example -- VisualSVNServerHooks: E020014: The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server response was: 550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 u9si1539700wiz.121 - gsmtp

Comment: One more error I got is : VisualSVNServerHooks.exe: invalid option: --cc